# Static / Non-Static Method Issue

Tags: php, oop

I am working on a simple ORM solution and have run into a tricky situation. Ideally, I'd like to be able to use methods in both a static context, and object context depending on how it is called. I am not sure if this is possible, but here is what I mean:

Say a User model wants to call where() statically, this currently works fine, for example:

```
$user = User::where('id = ?', 3);
```

Now, I also support relationships, for example a user can have messages. When this relationship is established I simply store a blank copy of a message model in the user model and set a foreign key. For example:

```
$user -> messages = new Message();
$user -> messages -> foreign_key = 'user_id';
```

Now, ideally, I would like to be able to call:

```
$user -> messages -> where('unread = ?', 1);
```

In a non-static context and make use of $this -> foreign_key when in this context so as to only pull messages where the foreign key matches the user's id. Is this type of context-switching possible in PHP? Any reference to $this from static context throws an error as its a static method and should not rely on $this (for obvious reasons, when being called from a static context, $this won't exist)

Are there any clever ways around this? I tried overloading the method to have two different prototypes, both with and without the static keyword but this threw a re-declaration error.

Comment: $user = User::find(); what do you want this to return if it does not specify a foreign key?

Comment: It seems like in the top use, `find()` is a (static) function in the `User` class, but in the bottom use, `find()` is a method in the `Message` class.  Which one is it?  Both?

Comment: Perhaps that was an unclear example, I left out the parameters as they seemed irrelevant to the question but I will clear it up with a more accurate representation of how it would really work.

Comment: @jedwards - they both inherit from the same base class, currently it is declared as static in the base class, but as stated in the question I am ideally looking for a way to call it from either context.

Comment: static methods can't use $this, because they're not invoked in an object context, so there ISN'T a $this to work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After quite a bit of playing around, I have found a way to make this workable without the `Strict Standards` error mentioned by @drew010. I don't like it, it feels horrible, but it does work so I shall post this anyway.

Basically the idea is to make the method you want to be accessible `private` and `static`. You then define the `__call()` and `__callStatic()` magic methods, so that they will call the private static method. Now you may think "this doesn't solve the problem, I'm still stuck in a static context" - which you are but for a minor addition, you can append `$this` to the arguments passed to the actual method in `__call()` and fetch this as the last argument to the method. So instead of referencing `$this` in an object context, you reference the third argument to get a reference to your own instance.

I'm probably not explaining this very well, just have a look at [this code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dMSs6d):

```
<?php

class test_class {

    private $instanceProperty = 'value';

    private static function where ($arg1, $arg2, $obj = NULL) {
        if (isset($obj)) {
            echo "I'm in an object context ($arg1, $arg2): I can access the instance variable: $obj->instanceProperty<br>\n";
        } else {
            echo "I'm in a static context ($arg1, $arg2)<br>\n";
        }
    }

    public function __call ($method, $args) {
        $method = "self::$method";
        if (is_callable($method)) {
            $args[] = $this;
            return call_user_func_array($method, $args);
        }
    }

    public static function __callStatic ($method, $args) {
        $method = "self::$method";
        if (is_callable($method)) {
            return call_user_func_array($method, $args);
        }
    }

}

test_class::where('unread = ?', 1);

$obj = new test_class();
$obj->where('unread = ?', 2);
```

Comment: I actually quite like this solution, this is clever way around the limitations. I don't necessary like circumventing the way the language was meant to be used, but this would add some simplicity to the overall scheme. Other than circumventing the natural language intention, I suppose there would be a performance hit from using it this way, but may be worth it as the fact that they're the same under the hood is invisible to the end user. Are there any other reasons you would suggest not using this type of overloading?

Comment: The most important reason I wouldn't do this is because when I come back to it in two years I'll have no idea what this code does and I'll have to spend 10 minutes working it out. If you do this, comment it well! In terms of a performance hit you're talking about microseconds probably, but you would have to be concious of the fact that the code above allows access to every single method of the object/class, public or otherwise - so you would probably want to check `$method` against a white list of methods that are allowed to be accessed like this.

Comment: You might also need to perform some additional validation against the number of supplied arguments, especially in an object context. This is because PHP will not complain about an incorrect number of arguments passed because it has no fixed definition to check it against, and because of the nature of the way it works by appending `$this` to the arguments, if you supply the wrong number of arguments the object will be passed to the wrong parameter.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply! I will accept this answer as it most directly addresses the question asked, although all the answers were great and very helpful, thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of any way to do this without going against PHP standards and using the language in a way it wasn't meant to be used.

A function is either static or not.  Yes PHP allows you to call it either way but this does violate strict standards and the only reason you can get away with doing this is for backwards compatibility with older PHP 4 code where static didn't exist as a keyword.

Consider this code:

```
<?php

class Test {
    protected $_userId;

    public function find()
    {
        if (isset($this)) {
            echo "Not static.<br />\n";
        } else {
            echo "Static.<br />\n";
        }
    }
}

$t = new Test();
$t->find();

Test::find();
```

The output is:

> Not static.
>   Static.

But with error reporting turned on, this is the actual output:

> Not static.
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Test::find() should not be called
>   statically in test.php on line 19
>   Static.

If you declare the method as static, then it is static no matter which way it was called.

So I suppose the answer is Yes, you can do it using this workaround, but I wouldn't recommend it.  If you want to have it both ways, I would suggest adding two methods, `public function find()` and `public static function findStatic()`.

Since your code is either going to be written as `$obj->find()` or `Class::find()`, you can just as easily use the static vs. non-static methods in my opinion rather than having one method behave statically.  To adhere to DRY, I suppose one method would leverage the other one for doing the actual finding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was coming to this conclusion as well as I got the same strict standards errors in my test. Was hoping to be able to use the same name as I have 6-7 different methods that can be called which will all need a static named counter-part. But this does indeed make the most logical sense, was just hoping I might be able to hack my way around it ;)

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for not answering your question, but I have some comments that don't fit in a... comment. 
What you're doing is a bit illogical.

```
$user->messages = new Message();
```

You're creating a *single* message inside a variable called *messages*.
Do you mean `$user->messages[] = new Message();`?
Also, protect your class variables.

```
$user->messages->where('unread = ?', 1);
```

Here you're trying to SELECT from your user messages, it's nonsense.
What you should do is simply the same as you did for the `User` class: get the messages statically and then assign them to your user:

```
$user->messages = Message::where('unread = ?', 1);
```

If you need to look up for messages that have a specific primary key, pass it as a parameter to the `where` method, which can be enhanced to take many clauses:

```
$messages = Message::where(array(
    array('unread = ?', 1),
    array('id = ?',     $message->getID()),
));
```

I'd also like to add a personal note: creating an ORM is a great way to learn, but if you're looking for something more *serious*, I recommend you to give Doctrine or Propel a look.

Comment: Indeed, I am doing this mainly to learn. To address the oddity of storing new Message() in a $user -> messages...I did this as I was essentially looking for a way to mimic the behavior of User::where() from within the object context. As doing something like `$user -> messages = Message; $user -> messages::find()` does not work, storing a blank copy of the object and using non-static methods was the closest I could think of. But what you're saying makes sense, I just wish there was a more clever way to leverage the relationship between them without having to explicitly pass the foreign key.

Comment: You can pass a Message object to `User::addMessage()`, and in it, take the id of the message only (`$message->getId()`) and store it when you need to. -- When you fetch a user from the DB, then you'd either automatically get his messages (*eager loading*), or get the messages when the user asks for them (*lazy loading*). Make sure you don't ask for them the second time they're called.

Comment: Ah yes, this seems like a pretty clean solution as well. I will definitely be toying with these concepts tonight to try and find the best solution, thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

From the theoretical and practical point of view, it is not a good idea to have a class method which can be called both from the static and non-static context.

If you want to achieve accessibility of your class/methods throughout your application, maybe it would be a good start to read about Dependency Injection, Service Container and dependency injection oriented programming.

By implementing DI in your application, you will most probably loose any need for what you have mentioned.

I would suggest investigating trough web and you will find that static calls in context that you are working with is avoided and flagged as bad practice. Static/shared state in object oriented programming is something which should be avoided (as well as singleton pattern).

Dont get me wrong -> static methods have their purpose and benefits, however, the way you are using it is kinda obsolete (even though some frameworks, like Laravel, promotes this bad practice - e.g. "Facades" and Eloquent).